# Comic book/series about kids who travel different fantasy worlds but end up back in New York

Tags: story-identification, books, comics

There was a group of kids, and I think they traveled different worlds because they were in a fantasy land but back in New York City by the end.

All I remember is that in the end, a blonde girl goes through this shadow thing and dies. I also remember she gets a funeral pyre and there was a Viking. The blonde girl wasn't good with English and a red-headed boy liked her. The girl dressed differently too. In the end the boy who liked her is ripping up photos and letting them fly out the window.

It's a kids comic that was in my elementary school around the year 2010.